# Kendo UI Grid custom commands redirect

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, kendo-ui

I have a working grid (fields are name and id):

```
<grid stuff>
    <kendo:grid-column width="80px">
        <kendo:grid-column-command>
            <kendo:grid-column-commandItem name="delete" text="Delete">
                <kendo:grid-column-commandItem-click>
                //Here I want to grab this worker id and redirect the user to the url workerDelete.html?Id
                </kendo:grid-column-commandItem-click>
            </kendo:grid-column-commandItem>
        </kendo:grid-column-command>
    </kendo:grid-column>
    <kendo:grid-column width="80px">
        <kendo:grid-column-command>
            <kendo:grid-column-commandItem name="update" text="Update">
                <kendo:grid-column-commandItem-click>
                    // here I want to grab this worker id and redirect the user to the url workerUpdate.html?Id
                </kendo:grid-column-commandItem-click>
            </kendo:grid-column-commandItem>
        </kendo:grid-column-command>
    </kendo:grid-column>
</grid stuff>
```

I need to know how to capture the data from the row when the user presses the custom button and change the view, passing the data along on the querystring.
Iam using jsp and spring.

I tried to use the following code but it didn't work:

```
<script>
    function deleteWorker() {
        var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
        var row = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
        var id = row.id;
        window.location.href = "/workerDelete.html?"+cpf; 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the `grid-column-command` as follow:

```
<kendo:grid-column-command>
    <kendo:grid-column-commandItem name="update" text="Update" click="deleteWorker"/>
</kendo:grid-column-command>
```

and the `deleteWorker` function as:

```
    function deleteWorker(e) {
        var tr = $(e.currentTarget).closest("tr");
        var item = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(tr);
        // Do whatever else you need
    }
```

In this function `item` is Kendo Grid `dataItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Use template column.The template could be a button decorated with the **k-button**  class (so it looks like a kendo button) and custom class such as **deleteWorker** class.

Then you can add delegate event handler when the grid is initialized such as:

```
$('#gridName').on('click','.deleteWorker',function(){
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var rowItem = grid.dataItem(tr);
    var id = rowItem.id;
    window.location.href = "/workerDelete.html?"+id;
})
```